# what are the different ways to create an Arraylist and Hashmap in groovy

Tags: groovy

I have created an ArrayList like the following:

```
def list = new ArrayList()
```

But the codenarc report it is warning like following.

```
ArrayList objects are better instantiated using the form "[] as ArrayList"
```

What are the better ways to instantiate the collections?

Answer (score 18):

You can do:

```
def list = []               // Default is ArrayList
def list = [] as ArrayList
ArrayList list = []
```

And again, for `HashMap`:

```
HashMap map = [:]
def map = [:] as HashMap
```

The default in this case is a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
def map = [:]
```

Comment: no need of putting ':' simply we can write the same as def map = [] as HashMap

Comment: @Oda True, but I wouldn't use that as I couldn't say whether it will always work in future versions

Answer (score 11):

Typical is:

```
def list = []
```

other options include

```
def list = new ArrayList()
def list = new ArrayList<Foo>()
List list = new ArrayList()
def list = [] as ArrayList
List list = [] as ArrayList
```

and of course:

```
List<Foo> list = new ArrayList<Foo>();
```

Similar options exist for `HashMap` using `[:]`.

Comment: It should be `List list = [] as ArrayList`, I mean when using `[] as XYZ`, parenthesis are not included at the end

Comment: @Mahesha999 and four years later, my error is corrected! Thanks, I've edited.

Answer (score 5):

> But the codenarc report it is warning like following.

```
ArrayList objects are better instantiated using the form "[] as ArrayList"
```

IMO, this is bad advice on Codenarc's part as it assumes that the implementation type of `[]` is `ArrayList`. This is true today, but may not always be.

The simplest/best/usual way to create a `List` implementation is:

```
def list = []
```

If possible, I will usually write something like

```
List<String> list = []
```

Just to make it a bit more obvious what this list should contain, i.e. for the sake of code readability. If I wanted to create a specific type of list I would instantiate a `List` "the Java way"

```
List<String> list = new SomeCustomListImplementation<String>()
```

But in practice I can't remember ever doing this.

Comment: +1 I agree with almost all of what you say, but I don't think that parametrized types `List<String>` give as much benefit in Groovy as in Java. I feel like either `def list = []` or `List list = []` fits better with the Groovy mindset.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use a suggestion from codenarc?

```
def list = [] as ArrayList
```